# Axure Set Date Variables

Tags: date, input, prototype, axure

I have a two input type Date. I want to save selected values in variables and on the next page I want to display them. When I set this variables to "text on widget" and on the next page set text to value I have no results. In others example like dropdown list or input type text everything works fine.

[image: text on widget]

[image: text to value]

Comment: I did not notice, that I had hint style fill color set, when I deleted this option it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

you should select setText to *"value of variable"* instead of setText to *"value"*. Then choose the variable name that you had defined in the first page. thanks